# Limit users by custom taxonomy and user roles

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, theme-development, user-roles, user-access

This is not duplicated post!

I working on the custom theme and have 2 taxonomies: `bezirk` and `ortsgruppen`.

`bezirk` acts like main group and `ortsgruppen` is the sub group under `bezirk`. I need to asign for each `ortsgruppen` in which `bezirk` belong.

Both taxonomy are included in the `post` and custom post types `dabei-gsi`, `homepage-slider`, `team`, `travel`

All custom posts can have multiple `bezirk` and `ortsgruppen` or non, that depends where user want to place it.

I create new user role `bezirk_admins`and need to setup user roles by `bezirk` and `ortsgruppen`.

Here is the complete role setup:

```
add_role( 'bezirk_admins',  __( 'Bezirk Admins', 'mitdabei' ),
            array(
                'read_private_dabeis'   =>  true,
                'edit_dabeis'   =>  true,
                'edit_others_dabeis'    =>  true,
                'edit_private_dabeis'   =>  true,
                'edit_published_dabeis' =>  true,
                'upload_files'  =>  true,
                'read_dabei'    =>  false,
                'edit_dabei'    =>  false,
                'edit_others_dabei' =>  true,
                'publish_dabeis'    =>  true,
                'delete_dabei'  =>  false,
                'delete_others_dabei'   =>  true,
                'delete_private_dabei'  =>  true,
                'delete_published_dabei'    =>  true,
                'assign_bezirk' =>  true,
                'assign_ortsgruppe' =>  true,
                'publish_dabei' =>  true,
                'publish_slider'    =>  true,
                'publish_sliders'   =>  true,
                'publish_team'  =>  true,
                'publish_teams' =>  true,
                'publish_travel'    =>  true,
                'publish_travels'   =>  true,
                'delete_dabeis' =>  true,
                'delete_slider' =>  false,
                'delete_sliders'    =>  true,
                'delete_team'   =>  false,
                'delete_teams'  =>  true,
                'delete_travel' =>  false,
                'delete_travels'    =>  true,
                'delete_others_dabeis'  =>  true,
                'delete_others_slider'  =>  true,
                'delete_others_sliders' =>  true,
                'delete_others_team'    =>  true,
                'delete_others_teams'   =>  true,
                'delete_others_travel'  =>  true,
                'delete_others_travels' =>  true,
                'delete_private_dabeis' =>  true,
                'delete_private_slider' =>  true,
                'delete_private_sliders'    =>  true,
                'delete_private_team'   =>  true,
                'delete_private_teams'  =>  true,
                'delete_private_travel' =>  true,
                'delete_private_travels'    =>  true,
                'delete_published_dabeis'   =>  true,
                'delete_published_slider'   =>  true,
                'delete_published_sliders'  =>  true,
                'delete_published_team' =>  true,
                'delete_published_teams'    =>  true,
                'delete_published_travel'   =>  true,
                'delete_published_travels'  =>  true,
                'edit_slider'   =>  false,
                'edit_sliders'  =>  true,
                'edit_team' =>  false,
                'edit_teams'    =>  true,
                'edit_travel'   =>  false,
                'edit_travels'  =>  true,
                'edit_others_slider'    =>  true,
                'edit_others_sliders'   =>  true,
                'edit_others_team'  =>  true,
                'edit_others_teams' =>  true,
                'edit_others_travel'    =>  true,
                'edit_others_travels'   =>  true,
                'edit_private_dabei'    =>  true,
                'edit_private_slider'   =>  true,
                'edit_private_sliders'  =>  true,
                'edit_private_team' =>  true,
                'edit_private_teams'    =>  true,
                'edit_private_travel'   =>  true,
                'edit_private_travels'  =>  true,
                'edit_published_dabei'  =>  true,
                'edit_published_slider' =>  true,
                'edit_published_sliders'    =>  true,
                'edit_published_team'   =>  true,
                'edit_published_teams'  =>  true,
                'edit_published_travel' =>  true,
                'edit_published_travels'    =>  true,
                'read_private_dabei'    =>  true,
                'read_private_slider'   =>  true,
                'read_private_sliders'  =>  true,
                'read_private_team' =>  true,
                'read_private_teams'    =>  true,
                'read_private_travel'   =>  true,
                'read_private_travels'  =>  true,
                'publish_post'  =>  true,
                'publish_posts' =>  true,
                'delete_post'   =>  false,
                'delete_posts'  =>  true,
                'delete_others_post'    =>  true,
                'delete_others_posts'   =>  true,
                'delete_private_post'   =>  true,
                'delete_private_posts'  =>  true,
                'delete_published_post' =>  true,
                'delete_published_posts'    =>  true,
                'edit_post' =>  false,
                'edit_posts'    =>  true,
                'edit_others_post'  =>  true,
                'edit_others_posts' =>  true,
                'edit_private_post' =>  true,
                'edit_private_posts'    =>  true,
                'edit_published_post'   =>  true,
                'edit_published_posts'  =>  true,
                'read_private_post' =>  true,
                'read_private_posts'    =>  true,
                'edit_comment'  =>  false,
                'manage_categories' =>  true,
                'manage_post_tags'  =>  true,
                'level_0'   =>  true,
                'edit_files'    =>  true,
                'read'  =>  true,
                'edit_categories'   =>  true,
                'assign_categories' =>  true,
                'edit_post_tags'    =>  true,
                'assign_post_tags'  =>  true,
                'assign_funktions'  =>  true,
                'manage_media_categories'   =>  true,
                'edit_media_categories' =>  true,
                'assign_media_categories'   =>  true,
                'delete_categories' =>  true,
                'delete_post_tags'  =>  true,
                'delete_media_categories'   =>  true,
                'edit_media'    =>  true,
                'delete_media'  =>  true,
                'manage_place'  =>  true,
                'edit_place'    =>  true,
                'delete_place'  =>  true,
                'edit_others_media' =>  true,
                'delete_others_media'   =>  true,
                'unfiltered_upload' =>  true,
                'read_post' =>  true
            )
        );
```

Request is that inside WP Admin I need to limit access to all post types based on the `bezirk` and `ortsgruppen` and all views must follow that.

I writte class like this:

```
if(!class_exists('Mitdabei_User_Restrictions')) :
class Mitdabei_User_Restrictions extends Mitdabei
{
    // WordPress database (object)
    private $wpdb = NULL;
    // Current post type (string)
    private $post_type = NULL;
    // Current user data (object)
    private $user = false;
    // User capabilities (array)
    private $capabilities = array();


    function __construct()
    {
        global $wpdb;

        $this->wpdb         = $wpdb;
        $this->post_type    = $this->post_type();
        $this->user         = $this->check_user();

        // Join proper tables for the post where search
        $this->add_action('posts_join',         'posts_join');
        // Filter admin posts by bezirk and ortsgruppe
        $this->add_action('posts_where',        'posts_where');
        // Set group by posts ID
        $this->add_action('posts_groupby',      'posts_groupby');
        // Post Request
        $this->add_action('posts_request',      'posts_request');
        // Filter admin posts by bezirk and ortsgruppe
        $this->add_action('save_post',          'save_post', 99, 2);
        // Filter Bezirk
        $this->add_action('get_bezirk',         'get_bezirk');
        // Filter Ortsgruppe
        $this->add_action('get_ortsgruppe',     'get_ortsgruppe');
    }


    /* Filter admin posts by bezirk and ortsgruppe
    =======================================================*/
    function save_post ( $post_id, $post ) {

        if(false !== ($user = $this->check_user()) && in_array($post->post_type, array('dabei-gsi', 'post', 'homepage-slider', 'team', 'travel'), true) !== false)
        {
            $defaults = array(
                'bezirk'        => array(),
                'ortsgruppe'    => array(),
            );
            if($bezirks = get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'ipm_mitdabei_bezirk', true ))
            {
                $data_terms = array();
                foreach($bezirks as $bezirk)
                {
                    $term = get_term_by('id', $bezirk, 'bezirk');
                    $defaults['bezirk'][] = $term->slug;
                }
            }
            if($ortsgruppes = get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'ipm_mitdabei_ortsgruppe', true ))
            {
                foreach($ortsgruppes as $ortsgruppe)
                {
                    $term = get_term_by('id', $ortsgruppe, 'ortsgruppe');
                    $defaults['ortsgruppe'][] = $term->slug;
                }
            }

            /*
            $taxonomies = get_object_taxonomies( $post->post_type );
            foreach ( (array) $taxonomies as $taxonomy ) {
                $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post_id, $taxonomy );
                if ( empty( $terms ) && array_key_exists( $taxonomy, $defaults ) ) {
                    wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $defaults[$taxonomy], $taxonomy );
                }
            }
            */
        }
    }

    /* Filter admin posts by bezirk and ortsgruppe
    =======================================================*/
    function posts_where ( $where ) {
        global $pagenow;
        if(false !== ($user = $this->check_user()) && in_array($this->post_type, array('dabei-gsi', 'post', 'homepage-slider', 'team', 'travel'), true) !== false)
        {

            $terms = array();
            $i=0;

            $bezirks = get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'ipm_mitdabei_bezirk', true );
            $ortsgruppes = get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'ipm_mitdabei_ortsgruppe', true );

            if(!empty($bezirks))
            {
                $data_terms = array();
                foreach($bezirks as $bezirk)
                {
                    $data_terms[]="tt{$i}.term_taxonomy_id IN ({$bezirk})";
                }
                if($data_terms)
                {
                    $terms[$i] = '(' . join("\n OR \n", $data_terms) . ')';
                    ++$i;
                }
            }
            if(!empty($ortsgruppes))
            {
                $data_terms = array();
                foreach($ortsgruppes as $ortsgruppe)
                {
                    $data_terms[]="tt{$i}.term_taxonomy_id IN ({$ortsgruppe})";
                }
                if($data_terms)
                {
                    $terms[$i] = '(' . join("\n OR \n", $data_terms) . ')';
                    ++$i;
                }
            }
            if(isset($_REQUEST['bezirk']) && $bezirk = get_term_by('slug', $_REQUEST['bezirk'], 'bezirk'))
            {
                $terms[$i]="tt{$i}.term_taxonomy_id IN ({$bezirk->term_id})";
                ++$i;
            }
            if(isset($_REQUEST['ortsgruppe']) && $ortsgruppe = get_term_by('slug', $_REQUEST['ortsgruppe'], 'ortsgruppe'))
            {
                $terms[$i]="tt{$i}.term_taxonomy_id IN ({$ortsgruppe->term_id})";
                ++$i;
            }

            if(preg_match('/('.$this->wpdb->prefix.'term_relationships\.term_taxonomy_id IN \((.*?)\))/i', $where, $tax_match))
            {
                if(isset($tax_match[2]))
                {
                    $terms[$i]="tt{$i}.term_taxonomy_id IN ({$tax_match[2]})";
                    ++$i;
                }

                if(!empty($terms))
                {
                    $where = preg_replace(
                    '/('.$this->wpdb->prefix.'term_relationships\.term_taxonomy_id IN \(.*?\))/i',
                    '(' . join("\n AND \n", $terms) . ')', 
                    $where);
                }

            }
            else
            {
                if(empty($ortsgruppes))
                {
                    $where = preg_replace(
                    '/(^\s?AND)/i',
                    ' AND (' . join("\n AND \n", $terms) . ') AND',
                    $where);
                }
                else
                {
                    $where = preg_replace(
                    '/(^\s?AND)/i',
                    ' AND (' . join("\n OR \n", $terms) . ') AND',
                    $where);
                }
            }

            $where = str_replace('tt0', $this->wpdb->term_relationships, $where);

        }
        return $where;
    }

    /* Join proper tables for the post where search
    =======================================================*/
    function posts_join ( $join ) {

        if(false !== ($user = $this->check_user()) && in_array($this->post_type, array('dabei-gsi', 'post', 'homepage-slider', 'team', 'travel'), true) !== false)
        {

            $terms = array();
            $i=0;
            if($bezirks = get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'ipm_mitdabei_bezirk', true ))
            {
                foreach($bezirks as $bezirk)
                {
                    $terms[$i]="INNER JOIN {$this->wpdb->term_relationships} AS tt{$i} ON ({$this->wpdb->posts}.ID = tt{$i}.object_id)";
                    ++$i;
                }
            }
            if($ortsgruppes = get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'ipm_mitdabei_ortsgruppe', true ))
            {
                foreach($ortsgruppes as $ortsgruppe)
                {
                    $terms[$i]="INNER JOIN {$this->wpdb->term_relationships} AS tt{$i} ON ({$this->wpdb->posts}.ID = tt{$i}.object_id)";
                    ++$i;
                }
            }
            if(isset($_REQUEST['bezirk']) && get_term_by('slug', $_REQUEST['bezirk'], 'bezirk'))
            {
                $terms[$i]="INNER JOIN {$this->wpdb->term_relationships} AS tt{$i} ON ({$this->wpdb->posts}.ID = tt{$i}.object_id)";
                ++$i;
            }
            if(isset($_REQUEST['ortsgruppe']) && get_term_by('slug', $_REQUEST['ortsgruppe'], 'ortsgruppe'))
            {
                $terms[$i]="INNER JOIN {$this->wpdb->term_relationships} AS tt{$i} ON ({$this->wpdb->posts}.ID = tt{$i}.object_id)";
                ++$i;
            }

            if($terms) $join = ' ' . join(" \n", $terms);

            $join = str_replace('tt0', $this->wpdb->term_relationships, $join);

        }
        return $join;
    }

    /* Set group by posts ID
    =======================================================*/
    function posts_groupby ( $groupby ) {

        if(false !== ($user = $this->check_user()) && in_array($this->post_type, array('dabei-gsi', 'post', 'homepage-slider', 'team', 'travel'), true) !== false)
        {
            if(empty($groupby))
            {
                $groupby = " {$this->wpdb->posts}.ID";
            }
        }
        return $groupby;
    }

    /* Filter Bezirk
    =======================================================*/
    function get_bezirk ($prepared_args){
        if(false !== ($user = $this->check_user()))
        {
            if($bezirks = get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'ipm_mitdabei_bezirk', true ))
            {
                foreach($bezirks as $bezirk)
                {

                    if($bezirk == $prepared_args->term_id)
                    {
                        return $prepared_args;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else return $prepared_args;
    }

    /* Filter Ortsgruppe
    =======================================================*/
    function get_ortsgruppe ($prepared_args){
        if(false !== ($user = $this->check_user()))
        {
            if($ortsgruppes = get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'ipm_mitdabei_ortsgruppe', true ))
            {
                foreach($ortsgruppes as $ortsgruppe)
                {

                    if($ortsgruppe == $prepared_args->term_id)
                    {
                        return $prepared_args;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else return $prepared_args;
    }

    /* Check user permission and set data
    =======================================================*/
    private function check_user() {
        global $current_user;

        if(is_admin() && is_user_logged_in())
        {
            if($this->user !== false) return $this->user;

            $user = NULL;

            if($current_user)
                $user = $current_user;
            else if(function_exists('wp_get_current_user'))
                $user = wp_get_current_user();
            else if(function_exists('get_currentuserinfo'))
                $user = get_currentuserinfo();

            if (NULL !== $user && property_exists($user, 'roles') && in_array('bezirk_admins', $user->roles) )
            {
                if(empty($this->capabilities))
                {
                    if(property_exists($user, 'allcaps'))
                        $this->capabilities = $user->allcaps;
                    else
                        $this->capabilities = get_role( 'bezirk_admins' )->capabilities;
                }

                if(property_exists($user, 'data'))
                    return $user->data;
                else if(property_exists($user, 'ID'))
                    return $user;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    /* Get current post type
    =======================================================*/
    private function post_type () {
        global $post, $parent_file, $typenow, $current_screen, $pagenow;

        $post_type = NULL;

        if($post && (property_exists($post, 'post_type') || method_exists($post, 'post_type')))
            $post_type = $post->post_type;

        if(empty($post_type) && !empty($current_screen) && (property_exists($current_screen, 'post_type') || method_exists($current_screen, 'post_type')) && !empty($current_screen->post_type))
            $post_type = $current_screen->post_type;

        if(empty($post_type) && !empty($typenow))
            $post_type = $typenow;

        if(empty($post_type) && function_exists('get_current_screen'))
            $post_type = get_current_screen();

        if(empty($post_type) && isset($_REQUEST['post']) && !empty($_REQUEST['post']) && function_exists('get_post_type') && $get_post_type = get_post_type((int)$_REQUEST['post']))
            $post_type = $get_post_type;

        if(empty($post_type) && isset($_REQUEST['post_type']) && !empty($_REQUEST['post_type']))
            $post_type = sanitize_key($_REQUEST['post_type']);

        if(empty($post_type) && 'edit.php' == $pagenow)
            $post_type = 'post';

        return $post_type;
    }
}
new Mitdabei_User_Restrictions();
endif;
```

The main problem is that one bezirk_admin can have a one or more `bezirk` and only posts that have `bezirk` with no `ortsgruppen` can be displayed.

For now in my solution `bezirk` "admin" can manage also all `ortsgruppen` under `bezirk` what is not good.

I don't  need plugin solution. I need explanation how to limit posts in the loops, and taxonomies based on the 2 taxonomy rules and what hooks to use for this.

Thanks!